# CheckedListBox not updating when DataSouce changes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms `CheckedListBox` that I am binding to a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` containing a list of custom objects on a data model, however when I update the backing collection to the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` the list box does not update.

I have verified that the collection's `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `NotifyCollectionChanged` properties are correctly firing, as well as that the binding is at least somewhat valid as the `ListBox` does display the expected choices when the binding is first applied.

I have tried using a `BindingList` wrapping the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`, using a regular `ObservableCollection`, extending `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` to make the property changed events public, using a `BindingSource.Add` on the `DataSource` property, as well as directly setting the `DataSource` property.

At this point I'm completely unsure of why this isn't working.  I'd really like to get this binding working, as the alternative is manually modifying the Items object every time anything about the collection changes.

Form:

```
Form_Load()
{
  SetupCheckListBindings();
}

SetupCheckListBindings()
{
  CodeList.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", DataModel, "Codes") //List only changes programmatically
}
```

Data Model:

```
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Code> Codes { get; set; }
private ObservableCollection<Code> CodesInternal { get; set; }

public Model()
{
  CodesInternal = new ObservableCollection<Code>();
  Codes = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Code>(Codes);
}

public AddCode()
{
  CodesInteranl.Add(new Code()); //Doesn't update
}
```

Comment: please provide code.

Comment: Went ahead and added roughly what my code is currently.